# Best algorithm to find out common elements in all the given arrays

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, algorithm

suppose there are 10 arrays and we have to find out all the common elements in given arrays.

Currently I am selecting first array and for each element in the first array i loop through all the remaining arrays, but this increases time complexity.

Is there any good algorithm to do it with minimum no of comparisons ?

Comment: Because of the standard library functions available, there might not be a common algorithm that is best for both C# and C++.

Comment: Maybe you should use [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) instead of arrays as a data structure?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of the arrays.

**Hash-based approach:**

This assumes unique elements in each individual array.

Insert all the elements in the first array into a hash map of element to count, with count starting off at 1.

Then iterate through the remaining arrays, incrementing the count of each encountered element.

At the end, output all elements with counts equal to the number of arrays.

You can use `Dictionary` in C# or `unordered_map` in C++11. You can also use a sorted map here (e.g. `map` in C++).

**Sort-based approach:**

Sort all the arrays individually.

Iterate through all the arrays at the same time, maintaining a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) or [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) containing one element from each array. At each step, remove the minimum from the structure and add the next element from the array where that element was located.

Whenever the minimum = the maximum, output that value.

My guess is that this is probably very similar to what [`set_intersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20881814/1711796) does.

To deal with non-unique values in each individual array:
(i.e. the 'intersection' of `1 2 2 3 4` and `2 2 4 5` should output `2 2 4`)

- You need to remember when the last time you output a value was and only output a value after you've inserted a number of elements greater than or equal to the number of arrays.

  If you don't do this, you'd get many times too many results. Look at a simple example of intersecting `1, 1` and `1, 1` and `1, 1`. The expected output is `1, 1`, but this would happen:

  In structure: `1, 1, 1`
  Min = max = 1, output `1`
  Remove 1 that was in 1st array and insert 2nd 1
  In structure: `1, 1, 1`
  Min = max = 1, output `1`
  Remove 1 that was in 2nd array and insert 2nd 1
  In structure: `1, 1, 1`
  Min = max = 1, output `1`
  Remove 1 that was in 3rd array and insert 2nd 1
  In structure: `1, 1, 1`
  Min = max = 1, output `1`

  Now the output is `1, 1, 1, 1`.
- When inserting, make sure you always insert it after all other equal values (i.e. treat it as greater than them). To do this, you can simply have an auto-incremented unique ID as a secondary comparison value.

  If you don't do this, you can keep removing elements from the same array, which would quickly get you to a different element, thus you won't necessarily output the right number of non-unique values.

  As an example, if we intersect `1, 1, 1, 2` and `1, 1, 1`, you can just happen to repeatedly remove from the first array, getting to `2` in 3 steps, but, because of the above point, we only output every 2 steps, thus we'd only have 2 instead of 3 `1`'s.

Answer (score 3):

In c++ there is a standard algorithm [std::set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/). It works on two sequences that are sorted. I think you will hardly get better than that. Sort all your arrays and then call `set_intersection` sequentially to obtain the result. Overall complexity will be `O(N*log(N))` where N is the length of the arrays(or the greatest length if they have different lengths).

Answer (score 0):

If you are about C#, there is a great thing called [language-integrated query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx), which simplifies querying collections as much as this is possible and provides execution in parallel (PLINQ). In C# you simply have to [write inner join query](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join) for multiple arrays.

Comment: @Nabla What about joining with LINQ in cycle? It provides great "laziness" and takes care about all of this, so it is rather the best way

Comment: @Nabla: joins in Linq2Objects are O(n).